# Bootbox.js making its size a custom value throws dialogue off-center

Tags: bootbox

We are using the popular Bootbox dialogue for Bootstrap 3.
We would like to make it a custom size with code such as :

```
 bootbox.dialog({
        message: $("<div>").load(href, function () {
        }),  //load
        backdrop: true,
        onEscape: false,
        size:'small'
    }).find(".modal-content").css("max-width", "360px");
```

However, if we do that, the dialogue goes off-center. Is there any way to achieve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't any different than manual Bootstrap modals, in that you don't target `.modal-content`. The width of the dialog is (supposed to be) defined by `.modal-dialog`, so you have two options;

1) Update your target, like so:

```
bootbox.dialog({
    message: $("<div>").load(href, function () {
    }),  //load
    backdrop: true,
    onEscape: false,
    size:'small'
}).find(".modal-dialog").css("max-width", "360px");
```

2) Use the `className` option, and move your rule to your stylesheet:

```
bootbox.dialog({
    message: $("<div>").load(href, function () {
    }),  //load
    backdrop: true,
    onEscape: false,
    className:'custom-small'
});

/* your CSS */
.custom-small .modal-dialog {
    max-width: 360px;
}
```

The `className` value is applied to the `.modal` container, so you'd need a descendant selector (as shown) for the width to be applied properly.

[Demo jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpwcgbd4/1/)

Unless you can guarantee the response is super fast, you probably also want to revamp how you load the dialog's message, given that $.load (or any other AJAX function) is asynchronous:

```
$.get(href)
    .done(function (response) {
        bootbox.dialog({
            message: response,
            backdrop: true,
            onEscape: false,
            className:'custom-small'
        });
    });
```